# Verb with association with single verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs

I often see the same verbs used in different forms, 
for example: 取り受けます and 取ります. Both verbs mean to accept. In general 取り受けます means to take and accept. Like this example, there are a lot of verbs that can be used this way, i.e. on their own and in association with a second verb. How should I remember all these verbs and know where to use a single verb and where to use the combination of two verbs. Is there any general explanation?  And where can I find a list of verbs associations to remember?

Comment: Did you mean that 受けます means accept? 取る is not 'accept', it's 'take'.

Answer (score 1):

> i often see the same verbs used in different forms for example. 取り受けます　and 取ります both verbs means to accept, in general 取り受けます means to take and accept.

Don't you mean 受け取る and 受ける?

> As like in this way, there are lot of verbs can be used in this form: single and (association of two verbs).How to remember all these verbs and know where to use single verb and where to use the combination of two verbs.Is there any general explanation ?

No, you have to learn each different verb case by case.

> and where i can find the list of verbs(associaton) to remember ?

A dictionary.

Comment: how to search for the list of these kind of verbs ?

Comment: In English they are often referred to as "compound verbs" and in Japanese they are called "複合動詞". There is an article here about them: https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/komu-compound-verbs/